# WeatherKit⛈ iOS SDK 401 network error WWDC 2022

Tags: swift, wwdc, weatherkit

I am getting an error while running WWDC22 [Link](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2022/10003/)

I downloaded the sample Project from Apple from [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/weatherkit/fetching_weather_forecasts_with_weatherkit)

And I am able to run the project. But when I create a Demo project and added Weather fetching code getting I am getting Error.

**My Code:**

```
func fetchWeather() async {
       let service = WeatherService.shared
        var location: CLLocation = CLLocation(latitude: 22.7196, longitude: 75.8577)
        
        let weatherData = try? await service.weather(for: location, including: .current)
        print(weatherData)
    }
```

**Error:**

```
2022-06-22 17:31:48.470130+0530 WeatherAPIDemo[25490:231389] [Database] Attempting to invalidate an assertion that is no longer valid 2022-06-22 17:31:49.208346+0530 WeatherAPIDemo[25490:231387] [WeatherService] Encountered an error when fetching weather data subset; location= +/- 0.00m (speed -1.00 mps / course -1.00) @ 6/22/22, 5:31:48 PM India Standard Time,  error=invalidJWTResponse(Optional( { URL: https://weather-data.apple.com/v2/token } { Status Code: 401, Headers {
    Connection =     (
        close
    );
    "Content-Length" =     (
        0
    );
    Date =     (
        "Wed, 22 Jun 2022 12:01:49 GMT"
    );
    Server =     (
        Apple
    );
    "Strict-Transport-Security" =     (
        "max-age=31536000; includeSubdomains"
    );
    "X-Apple-Origin" =     (
        "8961098f-b238-3714-ba44-5b569c861456"
    );
    "X-Cache" =     (
        "TCP_MISS from a49-44-192-207.deploy.akamaitechnologies.com (AkamaiGHost/10.8.2-41841244) (-)"
    );
    "X-Content-Type-Options" =     (
        nosniff
    );
    "X-Frame-Options" =     (
        SAMEORIGIN
    );
    "X-REQUEST-ID" =     (
        "8c733cde-5aa3-499c-b555-05c5aab5e278"
    );
    "X-XSS-Protection" =     (
        "1; mode=block"
    );
} }))
nil
```

Comment: Do you have a membership to the Apple Developer Program? As you need to add WeatherKit to your provisioning profile.

Comment: Status Code: 401, means unauthorized. You probably need some authorization for this.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I tried a lot even I have added **WeatherKit** in Capabilities But didn't worked.

I thought the issue must be that I don’t have the Developer Account But then I realised that the Apple Demo Project is also working even without adding any Team (see below img for Apple Demo Project).

[image]

Then I just copy and pasted the same `Bundle Identifier` in my Demo project and Boom! it worked like Hell.

Answer (score 0):

Apple Developer Program membership is **required**.

From: https://developer.apple.com/weatherkit/get-started/

> **Requirements**
>
> **Apple Developer Program membership**
>
> Access to WeatherKit beta is included in the Apple Developer Program,
> which also provides all the tools, resources, and support you need to
> develop and distribute apps — including access to beta software, app
> services, testing tools, app analytics, and more.